# Where is the Project Settings file that controlls Physics settings in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

In the Project Settings folder of a Unity project I see a lot of .asset files that are the actual settings when a user goes to Edit -> Project Settings in the menu. However I can't find the settings file that is the Physics tab of the Project Settings, but I can see a Physics2DSettings.asset (which is not the same since Unity has different physics settings for 2d and 3d physics). So my question is where is the .asset file that governs the 3d physics?

[image]

I searched the Project Settings folder, googled "unity physics settings file" but nothing came up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the file is called DynamicsManager.asset, and not PhysicsSettings as I was expecting (and as it makes sense since the file for 2d Physics is called Physics2DSettings.asset). There you have it. Mystery solved.